# How to enter a server IP into a mysql table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a page which displays no of times visited and all the IP addresses visiting the web page.

For that I created a mysql table which displays new IP in a new row, but I am unable to execute it.

Most likely, the error is in entering server ip into the table.Here's the full code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Delta sys ad task3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'prabakar';
$dbpass = 'praba1110';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('server_IPs', $conn);
echo mysql_errno($conn) . ": " . mysql_error($conn). "\n";
$counter=1;
$flag=0;
$sql='SELECT * FROM IPs';
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
  if($_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]==$row['ip'])
   break;
  else
   $flag=1;
 
 }
if($flag==1)
{
 $sql="INSERT INTO IPs VALUES('$_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]')";
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
}
echo mysql_errno($conn) . ": " . mysql_error($conn). "\n";

$counter++;
print "No of times site visited: $counter

 IP Adresses visited:";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 print "$row['ip']";
 
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$sql="INSERT INTO IPs VALUES('$_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]')";`

Comment: that ^ and you don't seem to have selected your DB.

Comment: what's this? `<body>
<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>
</body>`

Comment: Use this on your query http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php that would have spotted the syntax error and use proper bracing techniques.

Comment: @JohnConde ...and we have an answer ;-) *ouch*, I think something bit me.

Comment: and this is dangerous code, that leaves you open to some serious SQL injection

Comment: I made a few changes to the code, still it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the extra quote:

Change

```
('$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']')
```

to

```
('$_SERVER[SERVER_ADDR]')
```

Comment: Yeah, [John said that...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830476/how-to-enter-a-server-ip-into-a-mysql-table#comment49705935_30830476). *Thank you John!*